# How to scan "nempe tenens, quod amo, gremioque in Iasonis haerens"

Tags: classical-latin, ovidius, scansion, metre, metamorphoses

Ovid's Metamorphoses 7.66, here I marked my attempt:

> **nem**pĕ tĕ/**nens**, quŏd ă/**mo**, grĕmĭ/**o**qu(e) **i**n/ **Ia**sŏnĭ/**s hae**r**e**ns

That makes the 3 first feet dactyls and the fourth one a spondee, but the answer from hexameter.io says the fourth is yet another dactyl (and also mentions there is an elision, so I probably got the elision right; unfortunately I can't see the correct scan itself).  The *i* in *qu-in* is parsed long, because the *I* of *Iasonis* is a consonant. I can't figure out what I missed.

Comment: I tried to scan it before clicking the link to see if I can still scan, and got caught out because I read the word as 'Lasonis' (misreading capital I for lowercase L). Consequently my scan was the same as yours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As often with tricky verses, the key is in the name.
The only way I can scan that right is reading the name as ***Ĭ-ā-sŏ-nĭs***.
The initial I/J of a name can easily vary between vowel and consonant in poetry, but in this case [Lewis and Short do give precisely the same reading I got](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=iason&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).

The first syllable of *Iason* goes into the fourth foot and makes it a dactyl instead of a spondee.
Your reading does scan properly and it would not be an unusual licence, but it seems that the canonical reading is with the vowel I instead of the consonant J.

Answer (score 6):

Just to make it clear what Joonas said explained in his post, here is the line scanned out:

> **nem**pĕ tĕ/**nens**, quŏd ă/**mo** || grĕmĭ/**o**qu' in ĭ/**a**sŏnĭ/s **haerens**

The reason the initial letter of *Iason* is a vowel is because it's not Latin at all: it's Greek, from Ἰάσων, and ancient Greek did not have a separate [j] phoneme (though Allen says that it was likely pronounced as a glide following the iota before another vowel).

So in words where we might expect a J in Latin, in Greek it's always vocalic. In Latin, you'll find the odd exception, but the general rule is that it's a poetry and most often scans like one (so [Iacchus](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3DIacchus) and [Iapyx](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3DIapyx) are trisyllabic and [Iocasta](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3DIocasta) and [Iasius](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3DIasius1) are quadrisyllabic).

Comment: Thanks. Is the naive spelling of *jiasoni* out of the question?

Comment: @d_e I'm not sure what you mean: naive?

Comment: well, I meant that if I had to spell it based on the sound, this is how I think is more natural way to do.  basically I just wondered why not to spell like this

Comment: @d_e Based on what it sounds, I think *ijason* is closer than *jiason* (cf. cmw's parenthetical remark), but *iason* is best. The pronunciation starts with a vowel, so it would be confusing to start the spelling with a consonant (J).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, I see. thank you both.